# Why do we want to pass a Class to a function

Tags: python, class

As Classes are first-class objects in Python, we can pass them to functions. For example, here is some code I've come across:

```
ChatRouter = sockjs.tornado.SockJSRouter(ChatConnection, '/chat')
```

where `ChatConnection` is a Class defined in the same module. I wonder what would be the common user case(s) for such practice?

In addition, in the code example above, why is the variable 'ChatRouter' capitalized?

Comment: The most common use case is when you need to pass a class to a function.

Comment: `ChatRouter` is capitalized because someone forgot to read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @MarkRansom not necessarily. `SockJSRouter` could create a class at runtime, so `ChatRouter` would be a class name.

Comment: @alpha123, thanks for pointing this possibility out, as well as for the answer below. Could you please provide a simple example of passing  a class to a function to create a class at runtime? While it is not direct answer to this question, it would be a nice supplementary/related info to know in this context. thanks!

Comment: @skyork utterly useless, but: `def subclass(cls): return type('', (cls,), {})` will create a new subclass of an arbitrary class `cls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Without knowing anything else about that code, I'd guess this:</s>

OK, I looked at the source. Below the line is incorrect, although plausible. Basically what the code does is use `ChatConnection` to create a `Session` object which does some other stuff. `ChatRouter` is just a badly named regular variable, not a class name.

---

`SockJSRouter` is a class that takes another class (call it `connection`) and a string as parameters. It uses `__new__` to create not an instance of `SockJSRouter`, but an instance of a special class that uses (possibly subclasses) `connection`. That would explain why `ChatRouter` is capitalized, as it would be a class name. The returned class would use `connection` to generalize a lot of things, as `connection` would be responsible for handling communicating over a network or whatever. So by using different `connection`s, one could handle different protocols. `ChatConnection` is probably some layer over IRC.

So basically, the common use case (and likely the use here) is generalization, and the reason for the BactrianCase name is because it's a class (just one generated at runtime).

Comment: Looking at the code in question (it's on Github), this explanation - while plausible, does not reflect reality.

Answer (score 1):

Passing classes around may be useful for customization and flexible code. The function may want to create several objects of the given class, so passing it a class is one way to implement this (another would be to pass some kind of factory function). For example, in the example you gave, `SockJSRouter` ends up passing the connection class to `Session`, which then uses it to construct a new connection object.

As for `ChatRouter`, I suppose this is just a naming convention. While Python programmers are advised to follow PEP 8, and many do, it's not strictly required and some projects settle on different naming conventions.

Comment: Yes, the important thing is to be consistent and not to mix naming conventions.

Comment: +1 for elaborating on a specific use of this practice, as well as on the code example given. Thanks.